# How to transition a hexadecimal number to a new hexadecimal number where the new nibbles represent the original hex number's decimal equivalent?

Tags: hex, decimal, mips

As an example, take hex number 0x04D2 equal to decimal 1234.

Can someone think of a process to transition 0x04D2 to 0x1234?

I am writing a program in MIPS and plan on taking each nibble of the new hex number and convert it to ASCII for printing, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the transition to the new hex number.  When I get the new hex number, the ASCII transition should be a piece of cake.  Even though I intend to implement this in MIPS, I'm more interested in a universal bitwise process or algorithm.

Also, I do know that MIPS can print the decimal number by integer_print syscall'ing the register, but I would rather do it the hard way.  Plus, I need the ASCII in the register for what I am doing.

So, starting with only 0x04D2, is it possible to make this transition to 0x1234?

Here are the conversions for hex, dec, bin:

0x04D2 = **1234** = 0000 0100 1010 0010

0x**1234** = 4660 = 0001 0010 0011 0100

Thanks!

Comment: What is the practical purpose for doing this?

Comment: @EdHeal        Maybe nothing practical for the real word, but needed for a project I am working on.  For MIPS, I am using the MARS simulator, and the write to file syscall only writes in ASCII, so if i need to write 1234, I have to make sure the register or array is using ASCII values 31 32 33 34.  The transition I described above is the only way I can think to make the hex variable 0x04D2 write appropriately.

Comment: Do repeated divisions by 10 and print the modulos + `'0'` in reverse order.

Comment: @Michael       Exactly what I was looking for.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks!